# Duration when animating ImageView is ignored

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to animate a sequence of images.

The change between images doesn't have to have an animation, but I'm using animations to control the time:

```
-(void)nextImage
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage%d",index++]];
    }completion:^(BOOL completed){
        if (index < 50)
        {
            [self nextImage];
        }
    }];
}
```

The images are changing, but no matter what I use in duration, it ignores the time and goes as fast as possible.

If I change the alpha, the same happens:

```
-(void)nextImage
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.imageView.alpha = 1 - index++/100
    }completion:^(BOOL completed){
        if (index < 50)
        {
            [self nextImage];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only some properties of `UIView` are [animatable:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html)

```
@property frame
@property bounds
@property center
@property transform
@property alpha
@property backgroundColor
@property contentStretch
```

The `image` property of a `UIImageView` is not animatable.

If you with to update the image inside a `UIImageView`, instead use a different technique, such as blocks:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC),    
    dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
       // update your image
    });
```

(Alternatives: `performSelectorAfterDelay:` or `NSTimer`. I recommend using blocks though.)

I think your alpha animation isn't working due to int truncation in your division. Try this:

```
self.imageView.alpha = 1.0f - (float)index++/100.0f;
```

The problem with your original division is that the expression `a / b`, where both are ints, is performed as integer division. So if `a` < `b`, the result will be `0` -- in other words, completely transparent alpha setting for all values.

Comment: Ok, but why is not working when animating the alpha?

Answer (score 2):

The alpha isn't working because you've written

```
self.imageView.alpha = 1 - index++/100;
```

Everything here is an `int`, so your results can only be integer values, i.e. 1 or 0. Use this instead:

```
self.imageView.alpha = 1.0f - index++/100.0f;
```

The compiler will be able to implicitly convert `index` to a float, but you could be explicit and write:

```
self.imageView.alpha = 1.0f - (CGFloat)(index++)/100.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible do this with `[UIView animateDuration:animations:completion];`
Try to use a NSTimer and call a function that change the image every step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIImageView animation properties too, for example:

```
// arrayWithImages
arrayPictures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:50];

// The name of your images should 
for (int i=0; i<=49; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage%d.jpg",i]];
    [arrayPictures addObject:image];
}

imageView.animationDuration = 0.5;
imageView.animationImages = arrayPictures;

[imageView startAnimating];
```

Depending of the quantity of images, you can have some memory issue and would have to animate images using a lower level solution.

Answer (score 0):

If their is only animation duration issue then may be animation not enabled as i faced this problem in my ios app. Here is the simple solution :

Only you need to add  [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]; before starting the animation block. so your complete code will be like this :

```
-(void)nextImage
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage%d",index++]];
    }completion:^(BOOL completed){
        if (index < 50)
        {
            [self nextImage];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not using `images` property of ImageView and set an array of the images you want to animate?

Comment: That will simply change the displayed image, there'd be no animation.

Comment: Please see the original question : "The change between images doesn't have to have an animation"